# C# How to expose events in DLL

Tags: c#, api, events, dll, delegates

I have a DLL that needs to expose "event subscription" so a App that uses my DLL can subscribe to a specific event to get data. (The DLL itself subscribes to an event from a SDK)
I am pretty new to events, so please be gentle with me and explain.

I have a DLL that looks for example like this:

```
internal class BaseClass
{
}
internal Class DerivedClass : BaseClass, InterfaceClass
{
  public event TrackingEventHandler NewTrackingEventObservations; 
  public delegate void TrackingEventHandler(Object sender, TrackingEventArgs e);
}
```

In my interface, I want to expose the delegate `TrackingEventHandler`.

Interface:

```
public interface InterfaceClass
{
  event TrackingEventHandler NewTrackingEventObservations; // <- Error: TrackingEventHandler is less accessable then the field NewTrackingEventObservations
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you’re getting is because `TrackingEventHandler` is contained in a class that is `internal` (only accessible by files within the same assembly, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)), but the interface you’re trying to expose is `public`. You can either make the containing class public, or define `TrackingEventHandler` outside of this class (it doesn’t need to be contained in a class definition).

Here’s an example of defining it outside of a class:

```
namespace someNamespace
{

    public delegate void TrackingEventHandler(Object sender, TrackingEventArgs e);

    internal Class BaseClass{ }
    internal Class DerivedClass : BaseClass, InterfaceClass
    {
      public event TrackingEventHandler NewTrackingEventObservations;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isnt this line the definition already? : `public event TrackingEventHandler NewTrackingEventObservations;`
I have my example from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542189/creating-a-event-in-a-dll-and-handling-the-event-in-a-form

Comment: You define TrackingEventHandler as public, but ya contained inside an internal class. The class access modified takes precedence, effectively making TrackingEventHandler internal as well.

Comment: Can you please provide an example on "... define TrackingEventHandler outside of this class... "

Comment: Updated answer with example.

Comment: I tried this. I get the following error: "DerivedClass does not implement interface member InterfaceClass.example"

Comment: Oh my bad, the name of the TrackingEventHandler "example" in the interface InterfaceClass was different from the one I used globally called "NewTrackingEventObservations". Thanks, it seems to work.

One last question: Is putting the defintion of TrackingEventHandler  outside the class bad practise?

Comment: Since you implement the event “example” in InterfaceClass, it must also be implemented in DerivedClass, since DerivedClass implements the interface InterfaceClass. Make sense?

Comment: It’s not bad practice. It actually doesn’t make sense to define the event handler in the class since multiple classes/interfaces use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179103/discussion-between-anon-and-sterling-c).